# Create two sub-arrays from an array and remove the original keys in PHP (in an elegant way)

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of some thousands of URLs, like:

```
$urls = array (
  0 => 'https://domain.tld/ARENA/000024171/NAV/000024171_front.jpg',
  1 => 'https://domain.tld/ARENA/000436478/ΚΟΡ/000436478_front.jpg',
  2 => 'https://domain.tld/ARENA/000436478/ΚΟΡ/000436478_1.jpg',
  3 => 'https://domain.tld/ARENA/000436478/ΚΟΡ/000436478_front.jpg',
  4 => 'https://domain.tld/ARENA/000436478/ΚΟΡ/000436478_1.jpg',
  5 => 'https://domain.tld/ARENA/000468507/ΜΑΥ/000468507_front.jpg',
  6 => 'https://domain.tld/ARENA/000468507/ΜΑΥ/000468507_1.jpg',
  7 => 'https://domain.tld/ARENA/000468507/ΜΑΥ/000468507_2.jpg',
  8 => 'https://domain.tld/ARENA/000468507/ΜΑΥ/000468507_front.jpg',
  9 => 'https://domain.tld/ARENA/000468507/ΜΑΥ/000468507_1.jpg',
  10 => 'https://domain.tld/ARENA/000468507/ΜΑΥ/000468507_2.jpg',
  11 => 'https://domain.tld/ARENA/000523508/ΠΟΛΥ/000523508_front.jpg',
  12 => 'https://domain.tld/ARENA/000523508/ΠΟΛΥ/000523508_1.jpg',
  13 => 'https://domain.tld/ARENA/000548703/NAV/000548703_front.jpg',
  14 => 'https://domain.tld/ARENA/000548703/NAV/000548703_1.jpg',
  15 => 'https://domain.tld/ARENA/000548703/NAV/000548703_front.jpg',
);
```

So I wanted to transliterate those 3-4 Greek letters (ΡΟΖ, ΠΟΛΥ, etc) in the middle of the URLs, so I created two assisting arrays for the transliteration correspondences, like:

```
$greek = array('Α', 'Β', 'Γ', 'Δ', 'Ε', 'Ζ', 'Η', 'Θ', 'Ι', 'Κ', 'Λ', 'Μ', 'Ν', 'Ξ', 'Ο', 'Π', 'Ρ', 'Σ', 'Τ', 'Υ', 'Φ', 'Χ', 'Ψ', 'Ω', ' ');
$latin = array('A', 'B', 'G', 'D', 'E', 'Z', 'H', 'TH', 'I', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'KS', 'O', 'P', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'Y', 'F', 'X', 'PS', 'O', '_');
```

Then I wanted to create two sub-arrays, maintaining the ordinal relation between the transliterated and the original URLs...

So I did this:

```
$urls['GREEK'] = array_values(array_unique($urls)); // This recudes the 20K+ initial rows to just 3.5K
$urls['LATIN'] = str_replace($greek, $latin, $urls['GREEK']);
```

But it kept the initial 20K+ (with a lot of duplicates, etc) rows of the $urls...

I could just do something like this to get rid of the initial rows:

```
foreach ($urls as $key => $value) {
    if (!is_int($key)) {
        unset($urls[$key]);
    }
}
```

But this doesn't look very elegant to my style of coding.

Then I thought about re-declaring the $urls variable using something like:

```
$urls = array('GREEK' => array_values(array_unique($urls)), 'LATIN' => str_replace($greek, $latin, $urls['GREEK']));
```

But PHP complained with a `Warning: Undefined array key "GREEK"`, and indeed doing it in one pass isn't possible as `'GREEK'` sub-array isn't defined yet when it tries to use it for calculating the `'LATIN'` sub-array...

Then I did it in two passes like:

```
$urls = array('GREEK' => array_values(array_unique($urls)));
$urls['LATIN'] = str_replace($greek, $latin, $urls['GREEK']);
```

But I didn't like this very much either...

Of course I also thought about using an intermediate `$tmp` variable to create the sub-arrays, then unset the whole `$urls` and re-set the `$tmp` sub-arrays to it. But again that's too many intermediate steps to achieve my goal...

What would you choose as a solution to this? Something like a one-liner to removing the numeric keys, keeping the `'GREEK'` and `'LATIN'` sub-arrays would be great...

Comment: I don't think there's an elegant way to do this. It's not a common operation.

Comment: If I don't remove the 20K initial rows, will there be a resources impact on the page? I mean, there is no particular reason for me to delete those. Later in the code I'm using the `$urls['GREEK']` and `$urls['LATIN']` so I could live with the initial rows in place if they're not to create extra RAM needs ..

Comment: What I meant is that it's not common to reuse the same array this way. Usually the associative array would be a different array from the indexed array. After you create the associative array, you can discard the indexed array, and the garbage collector will clean it up.

Comment: In my code I struggle to be using as short and descriptive variable names as possible. And because those are actually URLs in Greek and Latin, there is nothing more descriptive to use as a variable name later in the code than `$urls['GREEK']` and `$urls['LATIN']`... So would it be OK resource-wise to keep the initial rows in place in the array? To me, as I won't be using them later in the code, they'll make no difference... But what about performance?

Comment: I would name them something like `$urls` and `$urls_by_language`

Answer (score 1):

You can save the original length of the array and then remove all the indexed elements in that range.

```
$count = count($urls);
// Add your GREEK and LATIN elements here
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    unset($urls[$i]);
}
```

But in practice I would just do what you say at the end.

```
$tmp['GREEK'] = ...;
$tmp['LATIN'] = ...;
$urls = $tmp;
```

Comment: The last part of your answer is what I'll probably be doing, as I won't be needing to unset $urls first either... What about $tmp though? Wouldn't that need to be unset to free up the Ram used for it?